# Bash: Run a command repeatedly till it suceeds

Tags: shell-script

We have a helm command that succeeds sometimes.

Running:

```
cmd1 || cmd1
```

will run it twice if the first run failed. How do I keep running cmd1 till it succeeds with a sleep between each runs? Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

`until` will do that for you:

```sh
until cmd1; do sleep 1; done
```

This will run `cmd1` until it succeeds, waiting one second between each run.

If you want to avoid running forever, you can add a maximum number of iterations:

```sh
max=5; until cmd1 || [[ "$max" -le 0 ]]; do sleep 1; ((--max)); done
```

If `cmd1` succeeds, the whole expression will succeed, and `$?` will be 0. If the loop exits without having managed to run `cmd1` successfully, the whole expression will fail, and `$?` will be non-zero. You can use this to decide what to do:

```sh
max=5
if until cmd1 || [[ "$max" -le 0 ]]; do sleep 1; ((--max)); done; then
    echo Succeeded
else
    echo Failed
fi
```

or, more explicitly,

```sh
max=5
until cmd1 || [[ "$max" -le 0 ]]; do sleep 1; ((--max)); done
if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
    echo Succeeded
else
    echo Failed
fi
```

Comment: Note that `[[...]]` and `((...))`  imply a ksh-like shell,it's not valid `sh` syntax.