# Is there a way to "catch" /usr/bin/dpkg errors in a CI script and retry a few times?

Tags: debian, docker, dpkg

I have a multi-stage, multi-arch Docker build process using Docker's debian:latest image and the Chromium/Firefox packages from Debian Sid.  Sometimes when building the images, something fails with the following error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
#0 221.2  system-config-printer-common
#0 221.2  system-config-printer
#0 221.3 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I rerun the build, it then works. This suggests that it's not necessarily a broken package.  Because this is an automated build, I'm wondering if there is a way to "catch" these errors and retry whatever step failed automatically?

Answer (score 2):

If you’re sure the command will eventually succeed, you can retry it with `until`. In your container build:

```
until apt install package; do :; done
```

or if you’d rather re-run the whole build:

```
until docker build …; do :; done
```

[These commands can be adapted to retry up to a pre-determined number of times](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/730495/86440).

In your case however, unless you really do need `system-config-printer` (which would be surprising in a container image), you’d be better off avoiding its installation altogether — start by trying `apt install --no-install-recommends`.

Comment: I'm going to try this out.  What you did in your other answer with the "try this only X times" logic is exactly what I'm looking for.  These failures are happening on a CircleCI runner.  When the job fails, I can select "rerun from failed" in CircleCI and the build then succeeds, so I'm hoping if I can rerun everything automatically that it won't need as much manual intervention.  I'll update what happens here. Thank you.